# Issue with creating bean

Tags: java, linux, spring, spring-boot

I've a java/spring application(service) which runs fine on my machine(windows). But when I deploy the same to a linux box, I keep getting following run-time error:

```
Error creating bean with name 'xxx' defined in class path resource
    xxxx/applicationContext.xml]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; 
nested exception is
    org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
    instantiate [com.tangosol.net.NamedCache]: Factory method 'abc' threw exception; 
nested exception is (Wrapped)
    java.security.PrivilegedActionException:
    java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
```

Am new to java I'm not sure how to go about fixing this error.

Thanks.

Comment: Do all you entities have getters and setters ?

Comment: can you share this class : com.tangosol.net.NamedCache ?